# Using Meteor behind a proxy is not working

Tags: heroku, meteor, proxy, static-ip-address

I am connecting to an external Mongo DB that only accepts certain IPs. I have a Meteor instance running on Heroku, and I have a Quotaguard static URL that I am trying to route Meteor through so I can connect to the Mongo server from that IP. Currently I have two environment variables on Heroku:

```
HTTP_PROXY=http://user:password@1.2.3.4:5678
HTTPS_PROXY=http://user:password@1.2.3.4:5678
```

However, when I check the logs, the application was not connecting to the database from my proxy IP. It was connecting as if there were no proxy. Is there an extra step I must take on Heroku?

Comment: Https proxy uses a http Url?

Comment: @Jankapunkt it seems that changing the environment variables to anything doesn't even work. I don't think Meteor is even reading the variables

Comment: I thought the variables were intended for heroku or something. Meteor itself will not configure your proxy this is up to you.

Comment: Please see https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Meteor-behind-a-proxy. I thought these variables were all I needed

Comment: I see now. This guide shows you how to use meteor behind a proxy in development. This is used to download packages etc. while working behind a proxy. In production it is up to you to manage your proxy be your webserver and reverse proxy if you have. Please read the heroku documentation on proxy settings.